# Start exe file from cmd in windows 8

Tags: batch-file, cmd, camera

I want to make a bat file so that when I open it, it will take automatically a picture with the webcam.

I only could come up with this: 
CMD> start /D"C:\Windows\Camera" Camera.exe

but it does not work. 
Maybe I should add some parameters or something else.

Help!

Answer (score 0):

Does it immediate take a picture as you run Camera.exe?

You maybe given the wrong path.
You can also type start /? in cmd to find out the parameters.

Comment: No. It does not take a picture immediately. That's the point. The path is correct I think. When I open Camera app from windows menu, it shows me on the desktop what the webcam see. Then, I should press a button to take a picture. I would want to double-click something (for example a bat file) and then the webcam should only take a picture.

Comment: That's the problem. As you said you need to press a button in the camera app, but unfortunately batch script is not a powerful programming language that can recognize the key you pressed down. You can try to learn c++ or other powerful language.

Comment: Ok, I'll look for a solution in C++ then. Do you know a function which would help me? It would make my search easier.

Comment: I'm not familiar with c++, but i'm quite sure that first you need to get the source code of the camera app, think not possible. And write a function that change the variable, change false to true or anything that can run the app without pressing the button. For instance, plug-in has the same theory that can change something inside the app and becoming it  more useful. Hope this help you. 